# Google Earth Engine - missing share button of assets

Tags: google-earth-engine

The share button of assets is missing. I uploaded an image (GeoTIFF file) but I can't share it.
Which settings should I check to restore this share function?

[image: Assets - missing share button]

Comment: Click in uploaded image. It will appear corresponding function.

Comment: Unfortunately, the share function doesn't appear. Delete and import only appear.

Comment: Did anybody find a solution for this issue? I stumbled upon it as well. No button in the asset tab nor in the pop-up window. Curiously it changes, some day it is where it should be, some day it is not.

Comment: In my case, It was due to some extensions if you use google chrome. I recommend you check and then deactivate them

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share an asset you need to click on it and the Share button is on the pop-up window that opens, top right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is the product of some configuration in chrome, it is solved using another browser such as Mozilla.